# How to detect Esc keypress / Cancel Button on prompt window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Im unable to capture the esc keypress / cancel button press during the prompt window execution in Javascript.

Because of this, if I do esc / cancel on prompt, its incrementing 1st Value in the array. (answers[0] is getting incremented everytym).

```
  answers: new Array(5).fill(0),
  registerNewAnswer() {
    let userAnswer = +prompt(
      `${this.question}\n${this.options.join("\n")}\n(Write option number)`
    );
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        console.log(key);   /* This statement isn't getting executed on any key press.
    Esc key press / Cancel button press should exit the base function (registerNewAnswer) from here */
    }
    typeof userAnswer === "number" &&
      userAnswer <= this.answers.length &&
      this.answers[userAnswer]++;
    this.displayResult();
    this.displayResult("string");
  },
```

Comment: what is the `key` you are logging? I can't see it anywhere. Maybe try logging e.keyCode ?

Comment: I was trying to capture the key press (any key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed the number conversion in assigning place, So I can capture the null value.
Number conversion is done atlast.

PFB revised code.

```
let userAnswer = prompt(
  `${this.question}\n${this.options.join("\n")}\n(Write option number)`
);
if (!userAnswer || userAnswer.trim() === "") return; // 1st to capture esc key / cancel button & 2nd to capture single space input.
userAnswer = +userAnswer;
if (isNaN(userAnswer)) return;
typeof userAnswer === "number" &&
  userAnswer < this.options.length &&
  this.answers[userAnswer]++;
this.displayResult();
this.displayResult("string");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `document.onkeydown` wouldnt work on the prompt. It works when you press key on your HTML page.

Remove the preceding `+` from the `prompt`. You can detect the escape/cancel as the prompt will return `null` in `userAnswer`. The preceding `+` converts the `null` to zero.

Comment: Thanks... Got your point...
So I should check for null value, then to convert the input to number.